# How can i use zustand with server and client components?

Tags: next.js, zustand

i am using zustand store in my app inside server components but i can't pass storage to client components

I was found a solution about this issue on github and it's not worked. Now i will share with you the solution:

**store/index.js**

```js
import { create } from 'zustand'

const store = create((...args) => ({
  text: null,
  setText: (text) => set({text}),
  hydrateStore: (data) => {
    const [set] = args;
    set({ ...data });
  },
}))

export default store
```

**store/store-initializer.jsx**

```
"use client";
import { useRef } from "react";
import store from "./index";

export function StoreInitializer({ initialStore, children }) {
  const initializedBefore = useRef(false);

  if (!initializedBefore.current) {
    store.getState().hydrateStore(initialStore);
    initializedBefore.current = true;
  }

  return children;
}
```

**app/layout.js**

```
import { Open_Sans } from 'next/font/google'
import { StoreInitializer } from "@/store/store-initializer";
import store from '@/store'
export default async function RootLayout({ children , params}) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <StoreInitializer initialStore={{ store }} />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```